# Forcing a page to reload on android native browser

Tags: android, html, reloading

My question is "How can I force a webpage to reload in Android device so that all my scripts will run?"

We are working on a web based photo gallery where a user can upload their picture using Aurigma app.

Once the user uploads a picture with this app, the user is redirected to the same page from where the user started. But on returning, the page does not reload and the scripts fail to initiate again.

As the site is a desktop version to be displayed on mobile devices, I cannot use the JQUERY mobile to user "pageinit" method as well.

So looking for any pointer towards making a page reload fully on return.

This issue is occurring only on Android devices.

Thanks,
Nitin Suri

Comment: Why don't you add a simple javascipt to make browser refresh.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I have already tried these basic things. The android browser does not refresh the page or even reload the scripts that you want to execute on document/window.ready, it picks up the . It just re-paints the changed section of the page and does nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions described here:
http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers